# What is the equivalent node in UE4 for Blender's Musgrave Node?

Tags: unreal-4

I'm trying to recreate Poliigon's non-tiling nodes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VgtSL5ZpYc, in UE4, and the only thing so far I don't see the equivalent to is the Musgrave node https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/musgrave.html, though UE4 has Perlin 3D Noise nodes, I don't see octave control described here https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Rendering/Materials/ExpressionReference/Vector/index.html

Is there a way to accomplish this? I assume so, UE4 cannot not have it... unless they already have a non-tiling node function already, and I don't know about it.

Comment: Have you considered just using multiple Perlin noise nodes and weighting/summing the octaves yourself?

Comment: No sir, but given my adv degree in Applied Math and Statistics, and my complete ignorance of this subject, at least even a point in the right direction is helpful.  I will investigate that, tyvm.  I was hoping it was already done, so I could just plug and play.